# Install MinGW-w64 Compiler - MATLAB2013a or 2016a

Tags: matlab

the adds-on explorer doesn't work as it needs a renewal license ... Is there anyway I can install the compiler to use a "mex -setup" command ?

Comment: What is the "adds-on explorer" in Matlab?

Comment: An icon at the top right at MATLAB helps you to install new packages

Comment: Sorry, it is difficult to reproduce the error on my system. Did you try to install mingw?

Comment: Yes I did ,I followed the instructions in https://www-m3.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M3/MeshFree1415/WebHome/matlabgnucompiler.pdf the (mex -setup) command had worked successfully but still fails to select the compiler

Comment: Did you follow these [instructions](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52848-matlab-support-for-the-mingw-w64-c-c++-compiler-from-tdm-gcc) and secondly, MinGW-W64 is only supported on R2016A.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions below will work on Windows 7 64 bit machine, for Matlab R2016Aa:

**System Requirements**

- -Windows 7 64 bit
  -Matlab R2016a

In order to be able to use LIBSVM package you need to have a C compiler installed on your system.

**How to install MinGW-w64 Compiler**

-In Matlab go to ENVIRONMENT section under the HOME tab
   -Click on Add-Ons > Get Add-Ons
   -Select Features from left pane under Filter by Type
   -Click MinGW-w64 tdm-gcc 
   -Click install
   -Support Package Installer window will pop up
   ---Get the URL -  MinGW-w64 Runtime http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/Sources/TDM%20Sources/
   --Download the executable
   --Make sure there is no space in the folder where you will download the compiler
   --Once the installation is completed, you should have a folder under C drive with a name TDM-GCC-64

**-Set Environment Variables in Windows**

- -Right click on Computer
  -Left click Properties
  -Click Advanced System Settings
  -Click Environment Variables
  -Click New under System Variables
  -Enter MW_MINGW64_LOC as Variable name
  -Enter C:\TDM-GCC-64 as the path (you installed compiler)
  -Click OK

**-In Matlab**

- -Set the current folder to Documents>MATLAB>Libsvm-3.2.2>matlab folder
  -Test Compiler using yprime.c file
  -Type copyfile(fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','examples','mex','yprime.c'),'.','f')

  -Set Environment in Matlab using the following command

  *YOU DO THIS EVERY TIME YOU START MATLAB AND WANT TO USE LIBSVM LIBRARY*
- setenv('MW_MINGW64_LOC','C:\TDM-GCC-64')
- Type make
- Type mex -setup (to choose suitable compiler for mex) You should get something like this:

  MEX configured to use 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)' for C language
  compilation. Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to
  support MATLAB    variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. In the
  near future   you will be required to update your code to utilize the
   new API. You can find more information about this at:
  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.

  To choose a different language, select one from the following:  mex
  -setup C++   mex -setup FORTRAN

  -Type mex yprime.c You should get the following result: Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'. MEX completed successfully.

  **-Test the compiler**

  > > yprime(1,1:4) You should get the following ans =

  2.0000    8.9685    4.0000   -1.0947
  -Type make to build mex files for libvm read write and others.
  -You may get the following error initially:

  > > make Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'. Error: C:\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016a\libsvm-3.22\matlab\make.m failed
  > >     (line 13) gcc: error: -fexceptions: No such file or directory

  -To resolve this issue, open make.m file and change CFLAGS= to COMPFLAGS, save it and call it again.
  -Successful installation will show the following

  > > make Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'. MEX completed successfully. Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'. MEX completed
  > >     successfully. Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'. MEX completed
  > >     successfully. Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'. MEX completed
  > >     successfully.

Comment: You will find Adds-On under Home tab, Environment section in Matlab R2016a. If you can't install MinGW64 from there, use the sourceforge.net URL provided at above to download the executable. Set environment variables as described, and follow the instructions.

Comment: Is there a way to generate MEX file from outside of MATLAB? For instance from Visual Studio solution directly. Thank You.